# Copy .xls sheet into .xlsm sheet

Tags: delphi, export-to-excel, xls, import-from-excel, xlsm

I have .xls file with several sheets. I have .xlsm file with several sheets. I want to copy xls.sheet(x) into xlsm.sheet(y). I tried the following code:

```
try
    XLTo := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    XLFrom := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
except
    ShowMessage('Excel might not be installed');
    exit;
end;

XLFrom.Workbooks.Open(filename1,1);
XLTo.Workbooks.Open(filename2,1);
SheetFrom := XLFrom.WorkSheets['Sheet Caption'];
SheetTo := XLScreener.WorkSheets['Sheet Caption'];
SheetFrom.Select;
SheetTo.Select;
```

Until here, everything looks OK, now I need to copy SheetFrom into SheetTo but I'm confused on how to do it. I tried:

```
SheetScreener.Copy(SheetDF);
```

But I got an error "copy method of worksheet class failed". SheetTo (xlsm) is a regular sheet with data that I want to override with the data of SheetFrom.

What am I missing?

I read the internet and saw several methods but I don't know if I fail because it's .xlsm or because I did something wrong. Also, I read that it had to be with the same Excel app but I'm copying from two different files so I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you want to create a new sheet in the target, or overwrite the contents of an existing sheet?

Comment: overwrite an existing sheet (SheetTo)

Comment: Don't you need to delete it first, and make a new one? Or will that break refs? If so then perhaps you need to copy a range rather than a sheet. Copying a sheet creates a new sheet.

Comment: All refs are invalid if I delete old sheet and copy the new one under the same name,

Comment: You got that right and I made it, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy a sheet, a new sheet is created in the destination workbook. I think you actually want to overwrite an existing sheet's contents. In which case do the following:

- Specify the source as a `Range` object in the source workbook.
- Specify the destination as a `Range` object in the destination workbook. Just specifying the top left cell suffices.
- Use `Source.Copy(Dest)` to perform the copy.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the sheet and insert it as last sheet try

```
SheetFrom.Copy(XLTo.Sheets(XLTo.Sheets.Count))
```

Then you can delete the original SheetTo - if this works for you

EDIT: Corrected syntax for delphi

Comment: It's delphi so I changed the code to this: SheetFrom.Copy(XLTo.Sheets(XLTo.Sheets.Count)); but I got "member not found"

Comment: Maybe you should create only one instance of the `Excel.Application` object.

Comment: I managed to open 2 sheets using the same excel app, now I get an error when trying to select a sheet

Comment: I'm no good in Excel automation, but do you actually need to select the worksheet object ? You have references to both worksheets, so why not just call that `Copy` method ? [it's a wild guess]